# Disable mixed content in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, https

Chrome 46+ simply [marks HTTPS pages with HTTP content](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/10/chrome-finally-kills-off-the-http-https-mixed-content-warning/) as though they were plain, "non-secure" HTTP websites. How do I get it to refuse to load this "mixed content"?

Comment: This depends on what you want to prevent to load. Chrome will only allow non-executing content (images, video, fonts IIRC) to load, but no JS or flash. Watch the dev console when browsing such sites.

Comment: @GiantTree, I think the OP was asking whether Chrome has something equivalent to Firefox's `security.mixed_content.block_display_content` or `security.mixed_content.upgrade_display_content` configuration settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I configure Chrome to block insecure content on mixed pages](https://superuser.com/questions/670499/can-i-configure-chrome-to-block-insecure-content-on-mixed-pages)